# How do I make perfect/critical shots?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

To unlock the *Knight Time Strike* AR challenge, I have to "perform 2 Perfect shots in a row in a drone tank battle". To unlock the *Untouchable* AR challenge, I have to "perform 3 Critical shots in one drone tank battle".

I'm told perfect/critical shots are actually the same thing. If so, **what is a perfect/critical shot, how do I make one, and how do I make two in a row?** If they are different, what makes them different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right next to the cannon, every drone has a blue glowing battery-like thingy. You need to shoot this with your vulcan canon (the machine gun on your bat mobile). To perform two in the row, you need to destroy two drones like this in quick succession without getting hit (like getting combo meter up while brawling)

[image]

Comment: Sigh. As you state in your answer, and what I failed to understand, I had to use my **Vulcan gun (R1)** *not* the 60 mm cannon.

Answer (score 3):

Aim at the glowing blue battery present on most tanks. Shooting it out will cause an instant-kill.

Hitting these glowing batteries counts as a critical shot.

Hitting these glowing batteries without making any other shot on the enemy counts as a perfect shot.

You can pretty much do this from the start, though Oracle will update you with the intel regarding the weak spot roughky a quarter to half way through the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily forcome losing your combo by double pressing A or X. Then you'll be able to double jump, if you do that over an enemy you will never lose your multiplier